# libGdx--Blank black screen when trying to load obj models using libgdx.g3d

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opengl-es, libgdx

I get nothing but a black screen when trying to load and render an .obj model using libgdx.
I have tried different models (exporting using blender in .obj format) I've tried loading .g3db files instead of obj files and come up with the same result. Nothing renders onscreen but my glClearColor (and yes I've tried something other than black to see if my model was rendering pure black) I have all the assets loading correctly for an .obj file (skeleton.mtl, skeleton.obj, texture.png) and I'm sure my code is doing something with them because if I remove say, the texture.png, I get an error saying it cannot find the asset. So why do I get NOTHING when rendering? I would like to understand why this is happening. Here is my code:

```
    public void show() {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(1f, 1f, 1f);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.near = 0.1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();
    ModelLoader loader = new ObjLoader();
    model = loader.loadModel(Gdx.files.internal("models/skeleton.obj"));
    instance = new ModelInstance(model);

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);

    ModelLoader loader = new ObjLoader();
    model = loader.loadModel(Gdx.files.internal("models/skeleton.obj"));
    instance = new ModelInstance(model);

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);
```

Then my Render loop:

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    camController.update();

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to clear my Depth buffer.

In my:

```
public void render(float delta) {
```

I changed this:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

to this

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

If you were using GL10 it would go like this:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I knew it was something stupid. I also made the changes suggested by the other poster about making sure my Transparency is set above zero in blender and also backing off my camera because the camera was too close, it wasnt rendering anything at that distance also. Thank you.

Comment: I cant believe it, I had THE EXACT SAME PROBLEM, you saved my day.  Gl state machine is so obscure^^

Comment: 2nd time this post saved me. Every time I blame the model importing/conversion process and it is just this. This time I was drawing 3D lines fine with `ShapeRenderer` and `ImmediateModeRenderer20` which was throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

```
cam.position.set(1f, 1f, 1f);
cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
cam.near = 0.1f;
```

Your camera is way to near the origin, so your object may be too big and the camera may be "inside" it, so it wont be rendered.

Also, you probably exported your object with zero opacity:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX#wiki-troubleshooting-missing-textures

> Also, it is quite common that the materials from Blender export with opacity set to Zero. If you notice your model is not being rendered. Go to the Material in Blender, and below "Transparency" set its Alpha to the desired one (usually 1, for full opacity).

Comment: I checked blender and the material opacity was set to 0 so I set it to 1 for full opacity. Exported .fbx, converted to .g3db, still nothing. I thought about the cam.near being too close but I do have CameraInputController(cam); enabled so I can scroll in and out with my mouse wheel, pan around with left click, but I see absolutely NOTHING on the screen but my gl.clearcolor. This is getting so frustrating, what am I doing wrong???!!
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);

Comment: Even if something was wrong with the texture, I should still see a mesh without textures or something don't you think? It's gotta be something simple..It's driving me nuts. I just want to know what I am doing wrong!